# How to override woocommerce widgets in child theme?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make some changes to widget named WC-widget-price-filter, I have created a new file with the same name with exact same root in my child theme directory:

my-theme/woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-price-filter.php

Changes doesn't appears, should I call the file from my child theme's functions.php ? and if so how can I ?

Thank you in advance!

---

So I tried to insert this code into my functions.php and made only 1 minor change which didn't appear. Done something wrong?

```
class My_Widget_Price_Filter extends WC_Widget_Price_Filter {
   /**
 * Output widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget
 *
 * @param array $args     Arguments.
 * @param array $instance Widget instance.
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    global $wp;

    if ( ! is_shop() && ! is_product_taxonomy() ) {
        return;
    }

    $min_price = isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['min_price'] ) ) : null; // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
    $max_price = isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['max_price'] ) ) : null; // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
    if ( ! wc()->query->get_main_query()->post_count && null === $min_price && null === $max_price ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-price-slider' );

    // Find min and max price in current result set.
    $prices = $this->get_filtered_price();
    $min    = floor( $prices->min_price );
    $max    = ceil( $prices->max_price );

    if ( $min === $max ) {
        return;
    }

    $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );

    if ( '' === get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
        $form_action = remove_query_arg( array( 'page', 'paged', 'product-page' ), add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) ) );
    } else {
        $form_action = preg_replace( '%\/page/[0-9]+%', '', home_url( trailingslashit( $wp->request ) ) );
    }

    $min_price = null !== $min_price ? $min_price : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', $min );
    $max_price = null !== $max_price ? $max_price : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', $max );

    echo '<form method="get" action="' . esc_url( $form_action ) . '">
        <div class="price_slider_wrapper">
            <div class="price_slider" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div class="price_slider_amount">
                <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="' . esc_attr( $min_price ) . '" data-min="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', $min ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Min price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
                <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="' . esc_attr( $max_price ) . '" data-max="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', $max ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Max price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
                <button type="submit" class="button">' . esc_html__( 'Filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '</button>
                <div class="price_label" style="display:none;">
                    ' . esc_html__( 'Price:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="from"></span> &mdash; <span class="to"></span>
                </div>
                ' . wc_query_string_form_fields( null, array( 'min_price', 'max_price', 'paged' ), '', true ) . '
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>'; // WPCS: XSS ok.

    $this->widget_end( $args );
}
}

function My_Widget_price_filter_register() {
unregister_widget( 'WC_Widget_Price_Filter' );
register_widget( 'My_Widget_Price_Filter' );
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'My_Widget_price_filter_register' );
}
```

Comment: Please add the widget code in your question…

Comment: Hey there, I simply want to copy the WHOLE file with all the code within it and make some changes to it..

Comment: You can't override a core function via your theme (like if it was a Woocommerce template)… It simply doesn't work and has no effect. As you have made some changes in the code of this cloned function, you should add the modified function in your question, to see what we can do in an other way. Changes can be done with action and filter hooks instead, via your themes function.php file.

Comment: Okey ! Well I thought I can override widgets just like templates.. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the Woocomerce widget in order to edit the content and then deregister the default widget to register yours:

```
Class My_Widget_Price_Filter extends WC_Widget_Price_Filter {
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        /**
         * Output widget.
         *
         * @see WP_Widget
         *
         * @param array $args
         * @param array $instance
         */
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            global $wp;

            if ( ! is_shop() && ! is_product_taxonomy() ) {
                return;
            }

            if ( ! wc()->query->get_main_query()->post_count ) {
                return;
            }

            wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-price-slider' );

            // Find min and max price in current result set.
            $prices = $this->get_filtered_price();
            $min    = floor( $prices->min_price );
            $max    = ceil( $prices->max_price );

            if ( $min === $max ) {
                return;
            }

            $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );

            if ( '' === get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
                $form_action = remove_query_arg( array( 'page', 'paged', 'product-page' ), add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) ) );
            } else {
                $form_action = preg_replace( '%\/page/[0-9]+%', '', home_url( trailingslashit( $wp->request ) ) );
            }

            $min_price = isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['min_price'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', $min );
            $max_price = isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['max_price'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', $max );

            echo '<form method="get" action="' . esc_url( $form_action ) . '">
                <div class="price_slider_wrapper">
                    <div class="price_slider" style="display:none;"></div>
                    <div class="price_slider_amount">
                        <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="' . esc_attr( $min_price ) . '" data-min="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', $min ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Min price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
                        <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="' . esc_attr( $max_price ) . '" data-max="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', $max ) ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Max price', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />
                        <button type="submit" class="button">' . esc_html__( 'Filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '</button>
                        <div class="price_label" style="display:none;">
                            ' . esc_html__( 'Price:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="from"></span> &mdash; <span class="to"></span>
                        </div>
                        ' . wc_query_string_form_fields( null, array( 'min_price', 'max_price' ), '', true ) . '
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>';

            $this->widget_end( $args );
        }
    }
}

function my_widget_price_filter_register() {
    unregister_widget( 'WC_Widget_Price_Filter' );
    register_widget( 'My_Widget_Price_Filter' );
} add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widget_price_filter_register' );
```

Comment: First of all thank you. Secondly I am not into coding that much so basically I would want use the code within the class-wc-widget-price-filter.php file and make some small changes within and then override the original file. That's the goal

Comment: Get the contents of the wp-widget-price-filter.php that is inside the WC_Widget_Price_Filter Class, then edit the parts that you wish to change.

Comment: I think I understand the logic, thank you I will go and try

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the widget code, edit /** Output widget. **/ section to edit what is displayed.

Comment: BTW is there a way register the new widget from my functions.php and use the class-wc-widget-price-filter.php file from the place I located it ?

Comment: You should be able to add that into your functions.php

Comment: Sorry sir I am not strong with coding just making my first steps :)

Comment: My main goal is the use the content of the original class-wc-widget-price-filter.php . For example to rename it, locate it in my child theme, make few changes, and override the original one.

Comment: Okey so I understand I cannot override widgets just like template by creating them in the same root as the original one right ?

Comment: That's correct, that only works for page templates and a good plugin will look for the same file name before using its own page template. The same with wordpress.