# Only Display Parent Category in Woocommerce 'Product Categories List' Widget

Tags: woocommerce

I am using the 'Product Categories List' widget inside a content block on the homepage of a website I am developing. Despite trying all the 'Display Types' available in the Woocommerce Category Editor, I cannot get the Subcategories to vanish from the list.
How do I simply display just the parent categories in the 'Product Categories List'.

Looking though this forum, I have found and tested lots and lots of PHP examples, all describing how to exclude specific products and categories from pages and posts within Wordpress and Woocommerce, but not one on how to simply display just the parent categories in the 'Product Categories List'.

I am certain a snippet of PHP will do this, but it eludes me.

Please, does anyone know how I can perform this simple task?

Comment: Just create your own widget ? Or modify the default one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571965/how-to-override-woocommerce-widgets-in-child-theme use as guidance how to do it. In addition here is the code of the woo widget - https://github.com/dipolukarov/wordpress/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/widgets/class-wc-widget-product-categories.php

Comment: Sorry, I would not know where to start creating a new widget or modifying the old one, hence the question. I am certain there is a way of doing this using a PHP snippet in the functions.php file, but I have a very limited knowledge of PHP coding. Again, that's why I am asking here.